# Inserting generated text into the same line as literal content with Haml

Tags: ruby, haml

```
document.write('
- @thumbs.each_with_index do |attachment,index|
  <div><a href="#..."><img src="#..." /></a></div>
');
```

The code above outputs something like this:

```
document.write('
<div class="item" style="padding:20;float:left;"><div class="item" style="padding:20;float:left;">
');
```

Is there any way I can accomplish the same but without the breakline that HAML creates? I need to make it something like this:

```
document.write('<div class="item" style="padding:20;float:left;"><div class="item" style="padding:20;float:left;">');
```

Answer (score 2):

Create and use a `one_line` block helper

### Helper

```
 def one_line(&block)
  haml_concat capture_haml(&block).gsub("\n", '').gsub('\\n', "\n")     
 end
```

### View

```
- one_line do
  document.write('
  - @thumbs.each_with_index do |attachment,index|
    <div><a href="#..."><img src="#..." /></a></div>
  ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [> and <](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_)

For exampel:

```
%ul<
  - 1.upto(5) do |i|
    %li> asdf
```

Will output a one line list.

In your case:

```
document.write('
- 1.upto(5) do |i|
  %div>
    %a{ :href => "#..." }>
      %img{ :src => "#..." }>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string interpolation in your template to inline Ruby code:

```rb
document.write('#{@thumbs.map.with_index{ |a,i| '<div>...</div>' }.join}');
```

For example:

```
require 'haml'
template = IO.read('tmp.haml')
puts template
#=> document.write('#{ @a.map.with_index{ |n,i| "<div>#{n}-#{i}</div>" }.join }')
@a = %w[a b c]
puts Haml::Engine.new(template).render(self)
#=> document.write('<div>a-0</div><div>b-1</div><div>c-2</div>')
```